# かと思った vs と思った difference

Tags: word-choice

For example, what's the difference between:

```
行くかと思った
行くと思った
```

They both mean "I thought I want to go"

Or another example:

```
猫だと思った
猫だかと思った
```

They both mean "I thought it was a cat"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

確度の違いかと思いました。

`猫だと思った` の方が `猫かと思った` よりも確信度が少々高い。

英語であれば、

```
猫かと思った -> I thought it'd be a cat.
猫だと思った -> I thought it was a cat.
```